# Trigger code on component v-show=true

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue 1.0.

1. I have a UI with tabs.
2. In each tab, there's a component that should load in its own data (via ajax).
3. I don't want to load every tab's component's data at once.
4. I only want to load the data once.

If I use v-if on the component and place the loading code in ready(), it loads every time the tab is selected. This is because v-if destroys and recreates the component. Is there a keep-alive equivalent for v-if?

If I use v-show, all tabs load at once. Is there a hook for when the component becomes visible?

Edit: because the comments keep mentioning dynamic components. I want to emphasise that **I can't use dynamic components** as the tabs require different properties.

Comment: explore v-cloak.

Comment: @Saurabh I am reading the documentation v-cloak. How do I trigger a method call with this? It looks it's an html attribute that is tied to the state of compilation.

Comment: Try and follow this tutorial https://coligo.io/dynamic-components-in-vuejs/ about dynamic components with the `is` directive. There is a point where `keep-alive` is introduced and used in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/coligo/43kxkm3d/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=43kxkm3d

Comment: I know keep-alive but I can't use dynamic components in this context.

Comment: Check this fiddle, is this what you need ? https://jsfiddle.net/srinivasdamam/jLukq3L9/

Comment: @SrinivasDamam As mentioned, I cant use dynamic components.

Comment: did you try [`beforeMount`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeMount)?

Comment: can you elaborate on why you can't use dynamic components?

Comment: @EliranMalka because I am reusing the same component for 2 of the tabs with the only difference being the property values being passed in. Some properties once passed in must remain static as there are async operations that are dependent on these properties. With dynamic components, the properties are changed even though it is inactive. The only way to achieve this is to break it in 2 components and setting the properties.

Comment: @EliranMalka before mount doesn't seem to be available in Vue 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v-if` together with `v-show`. When a tab is activated you set a property on it that is bound to the `v-if`. That makes the tab load. You do not unset that property.

A top-level property tracks which tab is currently displayed, and you use that in your `v-show` expression.

In the example below, each tab "loads" the current time at startup after a half-second delay. As you switch between tabs, you will see that each tab keeps its own time, it does not reload it each time it is displayed.

```js
var baseComponent = Vue.extend({
  data: function() {
    return {
      ajax: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => this.ajax = Date.now(), 500);
  }
});

Vue.component("tab-one", baseComponent.extend({
  template: `<div>Template for tab 1 {{ajax}}</div>`
}));

Vue.component("tab-two", baseComponent.extend({
  template: `<div>Template for tab 2 {{ajax}}</div>`
}));

Vue.component("tab-three", baseComponent.extend({
  template: `<div>Template for tab 3 {{ajax}}</div>`
}));

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tabs: [{
        label: 'Tab 1',
        component: 'tab-one',
        wasLoaded: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Tab 2',
        component: 'tab-two',
        wasLoaded: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Tab 3',
        component: 'tab-three',
        wasLoaded: false
      }
    ],
    activeTab: null
  },
  methods: {
    activate: function(tab) {
      tab.wasLoaded = true;
      this.activeTab = tab;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div class="tabs">
      <button v-for="tab in tabs" @click="activate(tab)">
        {{ tab.label }}
      </button>
      <tab-one v-if="tabs[0].wasLoaded" v-show="activeTab === tabs[0]"></tab-one>
      <tab-two v-if="tabs[1].wasLoaded" v-show="activeTab === tabs[1]"></tab-two>
      <tab-three v-if="tabs[2].wasLoaded" v-show="activeTab === tabs[2]"></tab-three>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```